# Changing URL index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In codeigniter 3 from git hub, I have tried to use the `enable_query_strings` but does not do what I am after.

I use index.php but also would like to add `index.php?route=` so then url would look like http://www.example.com/index.php?route=folder/controller/

But when I add it to my config index_page route does not work `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php?route=';`

Not work also with

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Hoe can i make the `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php?route=';` work with my url?

Comment: I think the url should be like index.php/controller/func/param/?querystring .
have you seen [the doc](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html?highlight=query%20strings#enabling-query-strings) ?

Comment: I would like to have index.php?route= before the directory. with no /

Comment: Why? If you are using sub folders in your application/controllers folder can't you just use as designed eg `www.example.com/index.php/folder/controller/`